# How does dependencies get picked in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, package, node-modules

To elaborate:
Lets say I have a react native project running on a specific version, and there are different npm packages installed, We know that each npm package will have its own node_modules and build.gradle file, In what scenario those dependencies local to that package will be used in my project and in what scenarios my project's dependencies will be used?

In the react native new architecture turbo modules are supported whereas I am using a library that does not has turbo modules enable is working, just wanted to know on what grounds the local versions of that package is being used and not the ones present in my project

Answer (score 0):

Let's say for example that you are using react-native-reanimated 2. This package has react-native-gesture-handler as its dependency. In most cases you'll have react-native-gesture-handler added as a local dependency as well.

Now, wherever you are importing reanimated 2 and using its functions, the react-native-gesture-handler of reanimated will be used, not your local one. In some cases, a conflict arises where different versions of dependencies make conflict. In that case you can use resolutions or override in package.json

In your specific case, if a library you are using does not support turbo modules then it will not work with new architecture because new architecture only supports turbo modules as native module.

Comment: Thats the issue, I checked the code of the package, It is still working even it doesn't supports turbo and the NativeModules written inside that package is working  @VinXi